# How do I find the area shared by the circles $r = 2\cos(\theta)$ and $r = 1$?

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

I figured out the intersection points:

$r=2\cos(\theta)$, $r=1$

$2\cos(\theta) = 1$

$\cos(\theta) = \frac{1}{2}$

$\arccos(1/2) = π/3$ (I), $5π/3$ (IV)

Comment: it would be easier to find the area that is outside $r = 1$ and inside $r = 2\cos \theta.$ then subtract this from $\pi,$  area of the unit circle. you can also do this without calculus knowing the formula $\frac{1}{2}r^2 \theta$ the area of the sector making angle $\theta$ at the center.

Answer (score 1):

The last integral is just 
$$2\int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/2}4\cos^2\theta\; \mathrm d\,\theta$$
All you have to do then is to linearise $\cos^2\theta$ with the duplication formula: from $$\cos 2\theta=2\cos^2\theta-1=1-2\sin^2 \theta,$$
you deduce the linearisation formulae:\begin{align*}\cos^2\theta&=\frac{1+\cos 2\theta}2,\\\sin^2\theta&=\frac{1-\cos 2\theta}2.
\end{align*}